# 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' after removing all NA

Tags: r

I searched the prior posts and they addressed that the cause of this error message: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed, is due to na values.  However I previously removed all my NA values so am confused as to why I am getting this error message.  I wrote a function to count whether the value in one column is greater than the value in another using control flow as per a class assignment. I am a beginner at R so would greatly appreciate any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.  My code is below:

```
testfunction<-function(x){
  x_2_columns=data.frame(x[34],x[23])
  x_2_columns_no_na=na.omit(x_2_columns)
  counter=0
  x_2_columns_no_na[,1]<-as.numeric(x_2_columns_no_na[,1] )
  x_2_columns_no_na[,2]<-as.numeric(x_2_columns_no_na[,2] )
  for(i in 1:nrow(x_2_columns_no_na)){
    if (x_2_columns_no_na[i,1]>x_2_columns_no_na[i,2])
    {counter=counter+1
    }
  }
  return(counter)
}

testoutput<-apply(df, 1, testfunction)
```

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

You use apply to loop over the data.frame. This means that your `testfunction` gets a vector of input and you make that into a new dataframe. Next by calling `na.omit(x_2_columns)` you introduce the following situation:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = 1, V2 = NA)
na.omit(df)
# [1] V1 V2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

which results in the error later on.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I modified the code after reading your explanation.  I now get output of multiple 1 and 0 rather than the number of the counter.  When I sum the 1 values from the output it also gives me a different total than the correct answer.  Modified code: testfunction<-function(x){
  x_2_columns=data.frame(x[34],x[23])
  counter=0
  x_2_columns[,1]<-as.numeric(x_2_columns[,1] )
  x_2_columns[,2]<-as.numeric(x_2_columns[,2] )
  for(i in 1:nrow(x_2_columns)){
    if(!is.na(x_2_columns[i,1]>x_2_columns[i,2]))
    {counter=counter+1
    }
  }
  return(counter)
}

Comment: Could you provide an example dataset? and what you would like as output?

Comment: My dataset is in a matrix format consisting of numeric values in the columns.  I would like to loop through 2 columns in the matrix, determine whether one has a larger numeric value than another, and then count the number of times this condition is met.  My output should be a single number.

Comment: wouldn't `sum(mat[, 23] > mat[, 34], na.rm = TRUE)` do that? Or is there a reason you need to do it with a for loop?

Comment: I need to use control flow for a class assignment despite its inefficiency. So I would greatly appreciate it if you have any additional suggestions on how to get this to work

Comment: okay sure, then I'd suggest you have another look at what the if statement with `!is.na(x_2_columns[i,1] > x_2_columns[i,2])` is doing.